# Python list efficientcies: bulk conversion of variables to str and list generation

Tags: python-2.7

So con is simply a condition that I am matching coming from a date generator I built. All output from this function is immutable. So I had the 'awesome' task of converting these outputs to strings. Reason being I wanted to append/prepend markup to the output. This gets very cumbersome when dealing with a lot of variables. 365 days to be exact.

```
con0 = str(context[0])
con1 = str(context[1])
con2 = str(context[2])
con3 = str(context[3])
con4 = str(context[4])
con5 = str(context[5])
con6 = str(context[6])
con7 = str(context[7])
con8 = str(context[8])
con9 = str(context[9])
con10 = str(context[10])
con11 = str(context[11])
con12 = str(context[12])
...
con364 = str(context[364])

day0 = con0[0:10].replace("-", "");
day1 = con1[0:10].replace("-", "");
day2 = con2[0:10].replace("-", "");
day3 = con3[0:10].replace("-", "");
day4 = con4[0:10].replace("-", "");
day5 = con5[0:10].replace("-", "");
day6 = con6[0:10].replace("-", "");
day7 = con7[0:10].replace("-", "");
day8 = con8[0:10].replace("-", "");
day9 = con9[0:10].replace("-", "");
day10 = con10[0:10].replace("-", "");
day11 = con11[0:10].replace("-", "");
day12 = con12[0:10].replace("-", "");
...
day364 = con364[0:10].replace("-", "");


exclude = [ '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day0 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day1 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day2 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day3 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day4 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day5 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day6 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day7 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day8 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day9 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day10 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day11 + "*" + '"', '  "/' + year0 + "/" + day12 ... + year0 + "/" + day364 + "*" + '"' ]

d0 = '  "*%s*"\n' % (day0)
y0 = '  "/%s/*"\n' % (year0)
w0 = '  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n''  %s\n' % (exclude[7],exclude[8],exclude[9],exclude[10],exclude[11],exclude[12]....exclude[364])
```

Is there a more pythonic way to make bulk string substitutions and generate lists easier than using my `for i` bash loops to build them for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have many variables all ending with a number, that's an excellent sign that you should be using a single list instead. You can concisely construct a list using list comprehensions.

```
cons = [str(context[i]) for i in range(365)]
days = [con[0:10].replace("-", "") for con in cons]
exclude = ['  "/{}/{}*"'.format(year0, day) for day in days]
w0 = "\n".join("  " + day for for day in days)
```